# Random Sudoku Generator

Tags: python, numpy, random, sudoku

I'm trying to build a python script that generates a 9x9 block with numbers 1-9 that are unique along the rows, columns and within the 3x3 blocks - you know, Sudoku!

So, I thought I would start simple and get more complicated as I went. First I made it so it randomly populated each array value with a number 1-9. Then made sure numbers along rows weren't replicated. Next, I wanted to the same for rows & columns. I think my code is OK - it's certainly not fast but I don't know why it jams up..

```
import numpy as np
import random

#import pdb
#pdb.set_trace()

#Soduku solver!

#Number input

soduku = np.zeros(shape=(9,9))

for i in range(0,9,1):
    for j in range(0,9,1):
        while True:
            x = random.randint(1,9)
            if x not in soduku[i,:] and x not in soduku[:,j]:
                soduku[i,j] = x
                if j == 8: print(soduku[i,:])
                break
```

So it moves across the columns populating with random ints, drops a row and repeats. The most the code should really need to do is generate 9 numbers for each square if it's really unlucky - I think if we worked it out it would be less than 9*9*9 values needing generating. Something is breaking it!

Any ideas?!

Comment: Did you try printing some values in that while loop and outside the if?

Comment: @Prune I think that this is the smallest code that would reproduce the problem... It's only 11 lines.

Comment: You're missing the "verifiable" part: this produces no output, and you haven't shown what you're getting vs what you expect.  You should also have some debugging results from your efforts to solve this: a few strategically-placed `print` statements, if nothing else.

Comment: @Prune It outputs between three and five lines (most of the time) of the Sudoku and it stops, it's trivial that what he wants is that the code finishes doing it.

Comment: Hi all, sorry I did have a few print statements in there. I took them out at some point before I copy-pasted it here! The main reason is that they wouldn't work sometimes - it would freeze up and when I hit stpp on the kernel it'd suddenly print a little more

Answer (score 1):

You are coming at the problem from a difficult direction.  It is much easier to start with a valid Sudoku board and play with it to make a different valid Sudoku board.

An easy valid board is:

```
1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
4 5 6 | 7 8 9 | 1 2 3
7 8 9 | 1 2 3 | 4 5 6
---------------------
2 3 4 | 5 6 7 | 8 9 1
5 6 7 | 8 9 1 | 2 3 4
8 9 1 | 2 3 4 | 5 6 7
---------------------
3 4 5 | 6 7 8 | 9 1 2
6 7 8 | 9 1 2 | 3 4 5
9 1 2 | 3 4 5 | 6 7 8
```

Having found a valid board you can make a new valid board by playing with your original.

You can swap any row of three 3x3 blocks with any other block row. You can swap any column of three 3x3 blocks with another block column. Within each block row you can swap single cell rows; within each block column you can swap single cell columns. Finally you can permute the digits so there are different digits in the cells as long as the permutation is consistent across the whole board.

None of these changes will make a valid board invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that your code is getting stuck in your while-loop. You test for the condition `if x not in soduku[i,:] and x not in soduku[:,j]`, but what happens if this condition is not met? It's very likely that your code is running into a dead-end sudoku board (can't be solved with any values), and it's getting stuck inside the while-loop because the condition to break can never be met.

Comment: Yeah, I felt this is what was happening. The console on my PC didn't really reflect this for some reason, seems like it just stopped printing even though it was stuck further along

Comment: Perhaps something you can try is recursion -- if we reach a dead-end with the current board state, we can backtrack up the recursion tree and continue again from the last board state that was valid (had a potential for a solution).

Comment: Yes!! I really like this idea - got to say it's a tad beyond my python experience. I was thinking of putting the whole thing within another while loop and if it got stuck (as it is now) it would be identified in an if statement that broke the while loop and repeated it maybe? I've seen a few examples of this done. Is that a kind of simplified version of what you meant?

Comment: Yep! I believe that would work -- in fact, that'd probably be faster since you don't have to deal with function call overhead

Answer (score 0):

Generating it like this is very unlikely to work. There are many ways  where you can generate 8 of the 9 3*3 squares making it impossible to fill in the last square at all, makign it hang forever.

Another approach would be to fill in all the numbers on at the time (so, all the `1`s first, then all the `2`s, etc.). It would be like the [Eight queens puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle), but with 9 queens. And when you get to a position where it is impossible to place a number, restart.

Another approach would be to start all the squares at `9` and strategically decrement them somehow, e.g. first decrement all the ones that cannot be 9, excluding the 9s in the current row/column/square, then if they are all impossible or all possible, randomly decrement one.

You can also try to [enumerate all sudoku boards](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204566/enumeration-of-solved-sudoku-puzzles), then reverse the enumaration function with a random integer, but I don't know how successful this may be, but this is the only method where they could be chosen with uniform randomness.

Comment: Fair enough, I get that this wont really work after reading the responses. The queens puzzle technique will keep me busy tomorrow! Hopefully I can get that to work

Answer (score 0):

I use permutations(range(1,10)) from itertools to create a list of all possible rows. Then I put each row into a sudoku from top to bottom one by one. If contradicts occurs, use another row from the list. In this approach, I can find out some valid completed sudoku board in a short time. It continue generate completed board within a minute.

And then I remove numbers from the valid completed sudoku board one by one in random positions. After removing each number, check if it still has unique solution. If not, resume the original number and change to next random position. Usually I can remove 55~60 numbers from the board. It take time within a minute, too. It is workable.

However, the first few generated the completed sudoku board has number 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 in the first row. So I shuffle the whole list. After shuffling the list, it becomes difficult to generate a completed sudoku board. Mission fails.

A better approach may be in this ways. You collect some sudoku from the internet. You complete them so that they are used as seeds. You remove numbers from them as mention above in paragraph 2. You can get some sudoku. You can use these sudokus to further generate more by any of the following methods

1. swap row 1 and row 3, or row 4 and row 6, or row 7 and row 9
2. similar method for columns
3. swap 3x3 blocks  1,4,7 with 3,6,9 or 1,2,3 with 7,8,9 correspondingly.
4. mirror the sudoku vertical or horizontal
5. rotate 90, 180, 270 the sudoku
6. random permute the numbers on the board. For example, 1->2, 2->3, 3->4, .... 8->9, 9->1. Or you can just swap only 2 of them. eg. 1->2, 2->1. This also works.